# How do I replicate the Apple Family Sharing Icon

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app

I was trying to replicate the following icon from Apple as a practice. I like the gradient effect but it seem to be shared by all the circles and the base. And there is also a opacity change, where all the circle has transparency, while the base has a gradient in opacity.

[image: Apple family sharing icon]

I tried the following to replicate it. Having circles with different color, and then an overlay with gradient opacity. but I seem not to be able to replicate the family sharing icon. Wondering if anyone knows how to do it.

[image: trial]

As shown, the color change is not what I wanted.

[image: Failed]

Comment: You've tagged both Illustrator and Sketch, can you clarify which program you're using?

Comment: Just circles and transparency.. with gradients lined up carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. I used Illustrator.

There's a flat cloud shape at the very bottom layer with a gradient, then the ones on top simply have gradients with varying opacity & angles. The top left and right circles are on "Multiply".

[image]